# Java Api Login Issue

Tags: java, api, jar, destructor

I am creating a API to allow end users to update my database.
I will put the API classes in a jar file and provide the jar to the user.

However I do want that the user should be authorised.(provide username and password)

Once the user has provided the user name and password do I have to check if user is logged in in every API call user is making?(I mean do I have to check in every getter and setter if user is logged in or not)?

Is their a different way?May be checking if user login credentials are correct or not?if not then destroying the object created?

**EDIT**

API which will be in jar file

```
import package org.atul.module.registration;

public class HelloWorld(){

  private bool isLogin=false;
  private String userName="user";
  private String Password="password";

  public HelloWorld(String userName,String password){
         isLogin = checkAuthentication(userName,password);    //will make true if creadential are correct
  }

  public String getInformation(){
             //return Information from database

}

 //other getters and setters
```

As I cant stop user from creating an object Do I have to check isLogin is true in every function(getter and seter) I make?

Comment: mm i need more to give a correct answer but you can return a proxy, you can make all classes final and without public access , only public the interface , and make a factory to create that classes, and there you pass the user and pass.. so there you dont have to check user and pass never cause you did when you create the object in the factory.. but this is vague cause i dont know your app

Comment: "and make a factory to create that classes, and there you pass the user and pass.. so there you dont have to check user and pass never cause you did when you create the object in the factory." Can you elaborate it to a newbie like me?

Comment: i need to know your appplication, what i said you if that your client code creates instances only with factories, for example ,, Factory.getSomeObject("keyForCreation",user,pass), and in your app you  don't make constructor visibility public... so there is no chances to use objects without user and password... if you think this can help you i make the answer

Comment: I am sure this is a noob way of making an API.Guide me some better way.:-).I dont want to make a webservice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a solution, may be is not the best but can help you. The intent is that you only can create objects with factories, so there you ask for user and pass. If you want you can make a cache of users logged in the superfactory to check if is it logged or not. I made you a simple diagram

create objects with the factory, register the user, throws an exception if doesn't exist pass and user.
In interface you declare methods that you want client use. 
Constructor access level for classes is package. So your clients can't access them only with factories.

[image: solution]

Another thing you can implements is like an `Interceptor` each request client gives you, pass to a class that check if is it logged the user.